# Can't click button using InternetExplorer.Application

Tags: automation, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to click the "Continue" button programatically using the InternetExplorer.application object on the page "http://www.dallascounty.org/criminalBackgroundSearch/".   When I click the button, nothing happens.
Below is my code:

```
loie = CREATEOBJECT('internetExplorer.application')
loie.Navigate2('http://www.dallascounty.org/criminalBackgroundSearch/')
loie.Visible = .T.
loSubmitButton = loie.Document.getElementsByName('Submit')
loSubmitButton.item[0].Click()
```

Until about a week ago, the button was clicking with no problem.  I realize there is also a capatcha on this page, but even if a manually click the "I am not a robot" box, I still can now programmatically click the "Continue" button on the page.  Could somebody please tell me what this site did to their page that is preventing me from programmatically clicking buttons and how to get around it?

I also would like to get passed that captcha programmatically, but that is a separate problem which I will deal with later.  However, if anybody has any tips on how to get passed that captha as well, I would be greatful.

Thank you